# Band insulators and the chemical potential

Tags: condensed-matter, chemical-potential, insulators

A quick question on the chemical potential in a band insulator. We all know that the chemical potential lies in the gap, which is fine, but the question is how can this happen exactly?

My thoughts are we need impurities and Anderson Localization (or something). The reason is if there are no states which do not localize, then the particle number constraint would not make much sense. For two different chemical potentials within the gap, we'd say there are different particle numbers. To me this means localized states need to exist within the gap.

We usually just put the chemical potential in the gap in an intro condensed matter course and just sweep how this can occur under the rug. We usually neglect impurities too, so I'm unsure if this picture of having a chemical potential within the gap even makes sense in such a case? If it does, and I am wrong, please explain how. Thanks!

Comment: How, experimentally, do you determine that something is an insulator?

Comment: This is a conceptual question on if it makes sense to even have a chemical potential in the gap if there were no localized states. If not, I'd think the chemical potential could only be at the top of the valance band because this would be the highest occupied state.

Comment: What's the chemical potential if you touch your insulator to a metal?

Comment: .... I'm asking about something different here. I understand what the chemical potential is and could explain various ways to describe an insulator. I was watching a physics lecture where the professor put the chemical potential in the gap willy nilly. I'm not convinced this makes any sense without impurities to support localized states in the gap. This is the question. Thanks for the replies, but I am thinking you are assuming I am more inexperienced than I am. No need to tell me what these things are experimentally when I want to know about what I previously asked SPECIFICALLY.